# Unable to update a table using sql query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I use sql server 2014.

I have a table in my ManuDB database called (waqf).

I am trying to update the table
but not allowed and a message (invalid object name waqf) appears.

I don't know what is the reason although I have a table called waqf.

[image]

Comment: Your query currently is in the `master` database (see the dropdown just above the `Object Explorer`) - and there's no table of that name in the  `master` database!

Comment: Oh =) ok done thanks alot ~~ still a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are executing the statement in Master Database as shown in the snip shot.

[image]

select the correct database from drop down list shown in picture or execute the following statement.

```
USE ManuDB 
GO

UPDATE ......
```

Comment: You'er welcome :) and dont worry its not only the new ones who make this mistake, people working with sql server for years still make this mistake but we know how to fix it.

Comment: ok can I ask a question ~~ I conected my dB with a website using visuall studio but I have a problem can I ask ?

Comment: Yes sure go ahead if I can help I will

Comment: ok In my my waqf table I have a column for images I only inseted the image link E.g w_img=N'Images/1.jpg'
in the website I connected evry thing but when I run the website all the table appears except the image I dont know why
the picture show the website and the image should appear inthe left
http://www.majaless.com/up/get-5-2014-8payeas0.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433003/images-dont-appear-in-my-website-that-is-driven-from-a-database

Answer (score 1):

From the drop down list of database; set it to `ManuDB`.

At the moment, it's pointing to `Master` which doesn't have your table.

Answer (score 1):

Type `USE <yourdatabasename>` before your update statement